# NodeJS ipcRenderer passing custom class as object

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I have two different windows controlled by index1.js and index2.js respectively. I create a custom javascript class in index1.js and I'm trying to parse that same class object to index2.js. I'm able to parse it but console.log function returns it as type '***object***' when called in index2.js and type '***Color***' when called in index1.js. How am I able to reference the ***Color*** object in index2.js. Any suggestions on the implementation.

> index1.js

```
class Color extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(hex){
        this.hex = hex;
    }

    getRGB(r, g, b) {
        return r+g+b;
    }

    getHSV(h, s, v){
        return h+s+v;
    }
}

function _init(){
    let electron = reqire('electron');
    electron.ipcRenderer.send('color', new Color("#FFFFF"));
}
```

> index2.js

```
window.onload = function() {
    const electron = require('electron');
    electron.ipcMain.on('color', function (myColor) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(myColor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should *reconstruct* object from receiver side.

Electron's IPC only sends serializable POJO, while `Color` inherits `EventEmitter` which includes non-serializable properties. To get same object, you need to send over serializable property then rebuild `Color` object in receiver.

Comment: If I reconstruct it on the receiver side won't I lose references to the instance from the senders side?

Comment: There is no way share reference between ipc process. You can't achieve it if it is your intent.

Comment: Can I share reference with a webview is that possible?

Comment: Again, no. All of ipc is between _process_, and you can't share reference between process as it doesn't share memory spaces.